# Where are historical data for the CIS Alert Level?

Tags: historical

The [CIS Alert Level](https://www.cisecurity.org/cybersecurity-threats/alert-level/) is a representation of the current state of cyber(in)security, globally.

There used to be a history of the levels, with an explanation for the changes (especially the rises). I cannot find it anymore - would someone know where it is currently hosted?

Note: I am aware of the subjectiveness of this or another measurement for "cybersecurity threat". I would be glad to use others, for the sake of completeness but I am currently especially interested in the historical aspects of the changes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this kind of information is now only available for members of MS-ISAC. If you're a U.S. SLTT government entity, you can submit for a free membership. But, if not, unfortunately there isn't any resource for alert history.

As an alternative, you can track the [advisory page](https://www.cisecurity.org/resources/advisory/) of MS-ISAC for last years track (~3 years) or [subscribe](https://learn.cisecurity.org/ms-isac-subscription) to their newsletter.